# Costs of using a website to send SMS

Tags: sms

I'm researching how to send SMS using PHP, the end product will probably be sending thousands a month.

I've found some pretty good tutorials, but none of them mention anything about pricing or sending limits?

Do I need to make payments to the Carrier? 
Will the recipient be charged if I don't?

I know there are services out there, that's my back-up plan, first I want to see if I can do it...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you'd need to set up your own [SMS gateway server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway).  I believe this requires a GSM modem, and SIM card.  It would be much easier and faster to go with an API service provider, like [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com).  You can get that up and running in a few minutes.

Comment: but if I were to get this server then I just pay through the SIM card installed?

Comment: I haven't done it myself, but I believe that's how you would pay the cellular carrier.  You'd want to get a plan with unlimited SMS.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [Amazon SNS](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/).